# List multiple translations via MS Power automate?

Tags: power-automate, google-translate, google-translation-api, power-automate-custom-connector

I would like to send in text + what language it's written in to Google translate, and in return get a list of that text translated into every available language, sorting order based on language A-Z.
Example:

Input
"How are you?"
Language: English

Output
African: Hoe gaan dit?
Albanien: Si jeni?
And so on...

And if possible, I would like to use Power automate flow for sending data into the api and retrieving it.

I'm a complete rookie so I'll need it described as such, I am kinda decent at power automate at least.

Hoping for help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use the ChatGPT API for that. Each call you make to a translate API (be it Google or Microsoft driven) will only be able to translate to one language at a time and each call will eat into your monthly quota. That’s my advice.